# What's the difference between "língua" and "idioma"?

Tags: diferenças, uso-de-palavras

*Idioma* and *língua* are two words, both translating to "language", which I never know how to distinguish.

I know that *língua* can mean "tongue" (and even in English "tongue" can also mean "language"), but I'm interested in the difference between *idioma* and *língua* when they mean "language".

(At least in English we wouldn't really say "the Portuguese tongue" for *a língua Portuguesa*.)

My dictionary (Aurélio) has

> ### língua
>
> [...]
>
> 4. O conjunto das palavras e expressões usadas por um povo, **por uma nação**, e o conjunto de regras da sua gramática; **idioma**.
>
> [...]
>
> ---
>
> ### idioma
>
> 1. **Língua** (4) **de uma nação**.
> 2. Língua (4) peculiar a uma região.

I'm not sure what to make of that. Does that mean I can use *idioma Português* to refer to European Portuguese?

#### tl;dr

What's the difference between *língua* and *idioma*?

Comment: In practice, none. *Idioma* is a bit more formal, and *língua* can also mean *tongue* depending on the context, but they are basically interchangeable.

Comment: @bfavaretto But I've never heard _idioma português_. Is _língua portuguesa_ a "set expression", then?

Comment: *Língua* is indeed more frequent next to language names, but *idioma X* is also acceptable.

Comment: It's almost acceptable. I don't recall ever have read or heard anyone using "idioma português". People will without a doubt find it strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Língua" and "idioma" are synonyms.

"Idioma" is a bit more formal, and as you already said, "língua" also means "tongue".

Though "idioma português" (or whatever other language) is not so common as "língua portuguesa", there's nothing incorrect to say like this.

So in brief,  they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it's common to use both without restriction.

However *idioma* relates to our official status about the language as a country and the *língua* is associated with the language spoken (mother tongue).

The *idioma* used in Brazil and Portugal is the Portuguese. The differences across the times are officially incorporated in both *idiomas* as Portuguese European and Portuguese Brazilian, but the *língua* will evolve in a different way.

Spain is a good example, because Spanish is the *idioma* and there is many *línguas* such as Basque, Catalan etc.

Some words of the *língua* are aggregated to the *idioma*, there is a example: tuite (tweet of Twitter)

You can use both words without problems and is good to know them, people usually says *língua*.

Yes, you can use idioma português, but is not common. I don't know what is the origin of Língua Portuguesa which is common to use.

Reference:
http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/diferencas-entre-lingua-idioma-dialeto.htm